# XOR returning jumbled values in C++

Tags: c++

I wrote the following function in C++ to perform encryption/decryption using XOR.

```
wchar_t* encryptDecrypt(const wchar_t* toEncrypt, const wchar_t* key)
{
    int strLength = wcslen(toEncrypt);
    int keyLength = wcslen(key);
    wchar_t* output = new wchar_t[strLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++)
    {
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key[i % keyLength];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Theoretically, encrypting a string twice using XOR should result in the original string:

```
wprintf(L"%ls\n", encryptDecrypt(encryptDecrypt(L"Hello World", L"Key"), L"Key"));
```

However, this is what's printed by the line of code above:

```
H??????????????????????
```

Attempting the same thing with an ASCII version of the same function seems even worse. Here is the function:

```
char* encrypt(const char* toEncrypt, const char* key)
{
    int strLength = strlen(toEncrypt);
    int keyLength = strlen(key);
    char* output = new char[strLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++)
    {
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key[i % keyLength];
    }
    return output;
}
```

printing code,

```
cout << encrypt(encrypt("Hello World", "key"), "key");
```

and output.

```
H²²²²A
```

Any ideas as to what may be causing this?

## Edit

Calculating the length of the plaintext and passing it in (as well as the output array), as some of you have suggested, solved most of the problem. However, there is still some junk at the end of the decrypted string.

Function:

```
void encryptDecrypt(const wchar_t* toEncrypt, int strLength, const wchar_t* key, wchar_t* output)
{
    int keyLength = wcslen(key);
    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++)
    {
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key[i % keyLength];
    }
}
```

Main:

```
const wchar_t* myString = L"Hello World";
const wchar_t* key = L"Key";
int stringLength = wcslen(myString);
wchar_t* encrypted = new wchar_t[stringLength];
encryptDecrypt(myString, stringLength, key, encrypted);
wchar_t* decrypted = new wchar_t[stringLength];
encryptDecrypt(encrypted, stringLength, key, decrypted);
wprintf(L"%ls\n", decrypted);
delete[] encrypted;
delete[] decrypted;
```

Output:

```
Hello World??ver????
```

Comment: You are trying to display characters that are not displayable due to the encryption, what did you expect?

Comment: Using `new[]` to allocated memory makes you responsible for calling `delete[]` to free it. The way you're calling these functions means you can't call `delete[]` and will definitely leak memory.

Comment: Returning a pointer to a dynamically allocated C-style string and hoping the caller will free the memory is a bad idea. It's better to have the caller supply the array to put the resulting string in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One problem that I can immediately see (there may be more) is that in your decryption function you are using `strlen()` on your encrypted data.

However, `strlen()` works on so-called "asciiz" strings, which are sequences of characters ending with a zero (`'\0'`) character.  Your encrypted data contains random bytes, so it is not an "asciiz" string. If your encrypted buffer contains a zero byte, then `strlen()` will return a number smaller than the actual length of the encrypted data, and your decryption will not work properly.

Specifically, I notice that both "Hello World" and "key" contain an 'e' in the second position, and XORing an 'e' with an 'e' yields zero, so there you have it, this particular text and key will yield encrypted data which, when viewed as an asciiz string, will appear to be only one character long.

To overcome this problem, you must stop thinking of your encrypted data as an asciiz string. Whenever you pass a pointer to encrypted data around, you also have to pass the length of the data, and never use `strlen()` to calculate the length of the data.

Amendment after the O/P's edit:

To fix the random characters after the end of the string, you need to remember that you are reading encrypted bytes and constructing an asciiz string.  Therefore, once you are done constructing the asciiz string, you need to *actually* make it asciiz by appending one more zero character to it, like this:

```
decrypted[stringLength] = '\0';
```

Also, you must not forget to account for that extra byte when allocating your decrypted string.  An asciiz string always occupies `strlen()` characters plus one, for the zero terminator.  So, you need this:

```
wchar_t* decrypted = new wchar_t[stringLength + 1];
```

Comment: In this case, since the key and plaintext both have 'e' in the second position, the second character is always '\0' after encryption.  Because the OP doesn't properly null terminate the output string, he correctly decrypts 'H' (since the string appears to be one character long) and then outputs random junk after that.

Comment: Or even better, use `std::string` :))

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 2):

You miss a nul terminator in your output. So now, computing the input length result in buffer overflow and undefined behavior.

To fix it quick and dirty:

```
char* encrypt(const char* toEncrypt, const char* key)
{
    int strLength = strlen(toEncrypt);
    int keyLength = strlen(key);
    char* output = new char[strLength+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++)
    {
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key[i % keyLength];
    }
    output[sizeof(output)-1] = '\0';
    return output;
}
```

Now, your code exhibit other problems:

- it leaks
- it is not C++, merely C with `new`.

Use the C++ with its tools. Not using the Standart Library is like speaking english but with only words without an e...

C++ simple implementation:

```
std::string encrypt(std::string plaintext, std::string_view key)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < plaintext.size(); ++i) {
        plaintext[i] ^= key[i % key.size()];
    }
    return plaintext;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e1ab26d0756ec4e)

Comment: Exactly--`std::string` is clearly the right way to go here.